# Why can't I install mysql-server on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 vagrant box?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vagrant

Basically what the title asks. I have a very simple vagrant file, as follows:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

box_name = "killd"

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

config.vm.define box_name do |box|
        box.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
            v.name = box_name
            v.memory = 256
        end
        
        box.vm.hostname = box_name
        
        box.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
        
        #box.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
        box.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10"
        
        box.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
            #ansible.verbose = 'vvv'
            ansible.playbook = "ansible/playbook.yml"
            ansible.limit = "all"
        end
    
        #box.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
    
        box.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host:3366
    
    end
    
end
```

I have a simple ansible playbook structure that just updates apt's cache and then runs `apt-get upgrade` with privelege for now (this definitely works). I would like to then go ahead and install the `mysql-server` package. But when I try to do so, even by just issuing `sudo apt-get install mysql-sever` through a `vagrant-ssh session` I receive the following error message:

> Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user
>
> An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.
>
> You should check the account's password after the package installation. Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.

I've installed mysql many times before on Ubuntu VMs and never seen that. Most of the answers I've come across relate either to the port number or previous versions of MySQL being installed, which is not the case here. Why am I having issues?